# the background moves when the resolution changes

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem again with my page. If you take a look at http://masluzz.panamerik.net/ you can see on the top the menu with the colors orange and gray.

I need this to look good on all resolutions, because when i´m changing the resolution, the color orange moves to the right side more than I want it to.

Here is my CSS and a direct link with a graphic preview.
CODE:

```
#sticky {
    padding: 0.0ex;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    color: #transparent;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.0ex;
    background: url(/img/layout/menu.png) 38.5% 0% repeat-y;
    border-radius: 0.0ex;
}
```

Preview image link:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkHfT.png

Comment: Why don't you set an absolutely positioned div that starts from the left of the page and goes to 50% of page width with orange background behind the menu? Then just set the elements you want to be orange as just orange. This is simple give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about the image and change it to CSS code. It's much easier when they want a change and more consistent. You will want to make the background of the menu orange then add a class to each

element that should be orange. ie.

```
<div id='menu'>
    <ul>
         <li class="orange">Option 1</li>
         <li class="orange">Option 2</li>
         <li class="grey">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then your CSS would look something like this.

```
#menu {background:orange;};
#menu>li {float:left; display:inline-block}
.orange {background:orange;} 
.grey {background:grey;}
```

The .orange could even be omitted since you are defining the #menu div's background. However, this may take some clean up on your site. I noticed several of the line items are different heights. And until this is cleaned up you will have issues with the backgrounds not looking right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media queries to change css code based on screen resolutions.

Example.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1360px) and (max-device-width : 1366px)
{
    #sticky
    {
       background: url(/img/layout/menu.png) 44.5% 0% repeat-y;
    }
}
```

This would be to set the width for that orange background between resolutions of 1360 and 1366px wide. Obviously you would want to widen the mins and maxs to meet your needs. You can use as many media selectors as you want to cover as many resolution specific changes you may need.

I forgot to mention originally that if you are going to use a media query you will need to take the original "background: url(/img/layout/menu.png) 38.5% 0% repeat-y;" out if you wish for the media query to be displayed. If you use this attribute outside of a media query for this id selector then it will override what is inside of your media query. In a real application of this solution you will need multiple media queries for different display resolutions.

Comment: Is your screen resolution inside of the min width and max width specified in the media query?

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1153px)
and (max-device-width : 1366px)
{
}

This media query i just copied and pasted out of a website i just completed and is known to work correctly.